# Managing the CSS direction for LTR and RTL

Tags: html, css

Here is the CSS/HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="Workbook-S-140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>CONGREGATION NAME Midweek Meeting Schedule</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
/* This is the default font for all cells */font-family: Calibri;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: #666;
}
.containerPage {
    min-width: 210mm;
    max-width: 210mm;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.containerMeeting {
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}
.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}
.borderHEADINGOuter {
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}
.borderHEADINGInner {
    border-bottom: 4px gray solid;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.tableHEADING {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.tableHEADING td {
    border: none;
}
.textCongregation {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.textTitle {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <div class="borderHEADINGOuter">
            <div class="borderHEADINGInner">
                <table class="tableHEADING">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
                        <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the jiggle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mL9j6zgz/

All is good. But, if I change the **dir** attribute to **rtl** and and **lang** attribute to **ar**, the layout is wrong. The two **div** objects are swapped correctly, but the text alignments are now wrong. They need to be reversed.

I know I can create two new CSS classes for RTL, and use the opposite text alignment, but is there anyway that the browser can manage this? I assumed it would swap alignments. Am I making sense?

In English:

```
<CONGREGATION NAME                     MIDWEEK MEETING SCHEDULE>
```

[image: English Example]

In Arabic:

```
<MIDWEEK MEETING SCHEDULE                     CONGREGATION NAME>
```

[image: Arabic Example]

**Arabic** HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="unsaved:///Workbook-S-140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>CONGREGATION NAME Midweek Meeting Schedule</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
/* This is the default font for all cells */font-family: Calibri;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: #666;
}
.containerPage {
    min-width: 210mm;
    max-width: 210mm;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.containerMeeting {
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}
.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}
.borderHEADINGOuter {
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}
.borderHEADINGInner {
    border-bottom: 4px gray solid;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.tableHEADING {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.tableHEADING td {
    border: none;
}
.textCongregation {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.textTitle {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <div class="borderHEADINGOuter">
            <div class="borderHEADINGInner">
                <table class="tableHEADING">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="textCongregation">اسم الجماعة</td>
                        <td class="textTitle">برنامج اجتماع وسط الاسبوع</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using tables you can't swap it. If you change your table layout to divs, you can make `float:left`  and `float:right` and viceversa targetting by attribute like `.textCongregation{ float:left; } [dir="rtl"] .textCongregation{float : right; }` With this little piece of code you'll achieve

Comment: What if I want to keep the table? Must I have two dedicated classes that have the text-align properties reversed? The rest of my tables automatically swap the cell text from right to left etc.

Comment: Yes, the text direction is fine, the problem is the html structure, you can't move a td from their place to another (swap the tds), and if I understand fine your question you need to make it

Comment: Setting my document to RTL will automatically render my cells in the reversed order. Swapping the cells is not what I want to do, it is reversing the text alignments.

Comment: OH well!! I misunderstood your question. It's easy with the attribute selector, I will write an answer right now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According with the comments we are talking in the main post, you can target with attribute selector and swap the text direction:

```
[dir="rtl"] .textCongregation{ text-align: right; }
[dir="rtl"] .textTitle { text-align: left; }
```

Learn more about attribute selector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

### A possibly better option

The `:dir()` pseudo-class selector may be preferable if the rtl is only defined on a parent element and not on a child element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir

You can see this in action at this jsfiddle where the body has dir attribute set to rtl but the child does not.

https://jsfiddle.net/ua8ksr1z/

Comment: This is no longer the optimal approach with advances in flow-relative CSS properties and values. Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

Advances in [flow-relative CSS properties and values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical/) make this much easier.

```
.textCongregation {
  text-align: start;
}
```

The following properties and values are well supported at this time across modern browsers. In parentheses are the older, commonly used LTR terms.

inset-inline-start (in place of left property)

inset-inline-end (in place of right property)

margin-inline-start (in place of margin-left property)

margin-inline-end (in place of margin-right property)

margin-inline (in place of margin shorthand property)

padding-inline-start (in place of padding-left property)

padding-inline-end (in place of padding-right property)

padding-inline (in place of padding shorthand property)

text-align: start; (in place of left value)

text-align: end; (in place of right value)

These values **currently only work in Firefox:**

float: inline-start; (in place of left value)

float: inline-end; (in place of right value)

Comment: At the moment I am using `CHtmlView` which uses an older IE browser so this syntax may not work. Most likely it will work when I migrate to `WebView2`.